# autosave .js files

Tags: macbook-pro, autosave

My dad is using my old MacBook that I used when I was studying web design and I see that the laptop still autosaves all .js files.
It's kind of cluttering the computer but I can't seem to find a way to disable it.
I used Visual Studio Code when I was coding so maybe the answer is somewhere over there.
If anyone might have an idea, all help is welcome

Comment: it also seems like profile pictures & headers get autosaved to my documents

Comment: give him fresh new OX with clean disk

Comment: Does it autosave all type of files(try to open a Pages document and see if it autosaves)? Do you want to disable autosave for all file types or just .js files?

Comment: What do you mean by "autosaves .js files"? Your dad probably doesn't edit JS, so which .js files get auto-saved?